# Writing "shorthand" references to fields within an object: The hows and whys?

Tags: java

First question here, so hopefully I'm not committing too many faux pas at the moment

**The quick version**: I want to save typing time by creating "shorthands" for an arbitrary (but known) field within an object's aggregation. (I think I'm saying that right -- still grasping certain terminology)

I'm not sure if there's a better/more accurate terminology for what I'm looking for here, and nothing I've come across has specifically mentioned this concept in Java (though I could have entirely missed something crucial in my search, and I feel that even though my familiarity is with Java, this question is probably more open to the world of OOP in general).

I'm pretty sure that if I got tired of writing, say:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
// ... more code ....

// This is a specific string I need to print out for "Foo"
if(reasonToFoo) {
    System.out.println(myClass.getSomeObject().getSubObject1().getDescription());
}
```

I feel as though I have two options: I can make a little helper function in the same class to "wrap" around that uglyish chain of object references, making it simpler for me to type out later:

```
public String getFooString() {
    return this.getSomeObject().getSubObject1().getDescription();
}

// ... elsewhere ...
if (reasonToFoo) {
    System.out.println(getFooString());
}
```

My alternative is to create a helper object that's sole purpose is to simplify snagging that same string

```
class FooString {
    public static String getFrom(MyClass mC) {
        return mC.getSomeObject().getSubObject1().getDescription();
    }
}

// ... elsewhere ...
if(reasonToFoo) {
    System.out.println(FooString.getFrom(this));
}
```

My questions are:

1. Do my approaches here effectively solve the "how" of the problem? As in, am I employing reasonable OOP practices in my solutions?
2. I'm having a hard time seeing a lot of the cases for "why" -- why would I want to use one version of dealing with this problem over any of the others? Are any of these implementations inherently worse than the others?

---

**[EDIT]**: Just realized I should probably not be accessing the objects within the instance of MyClass directly, and via getters instead. Editted accordingly

---

**Background**: I've dabbled in writing code in various forms and languages since the early 2000s (beginning with TI-83 BASIC, extending through some basic HTML/JS/CSS of that period, moved on for a period with ActionScript 3 and scripting in mIRC, before moving on to Java and Python) and am now a 28 year old freshman in college trying to get a better grasp on the design-side of programming while angling towards indie game development as a dream job (with the realization that a cubicle farm programming job is more realistic for paying the bills).

Comment: *"As in, am I employing reasonable OOP practices"* No, you are not. With `mC.someObject.subObject1.description` you are accessing fields directly, and it is OOP practice to hide the internals of a class, meaning all fields should be `private`, and accessible through getter methods only. However, creating an extra getter method on an outer class to get the value from an inner class is very valid, and actually help hiding the internals of the outer class, i.e. the fact that it is a composite class.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I realized the mistake in accessing fields directly after I posted, and updated accordingly. That wasn't the primary concern of my post, but it is indeed a valid point and as a student I should be paying more attention to things like that ;)

Comment: The second option would make sense if getting the Foo string is not just a simple fetch of the value but should be combined with a little processing, e.g., editing it in some way. Then `getFrom` should be a proper method, and you can have several `FooString` classes for various edit variants. But see also: the "Decorator" design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the object oriented point of view your code is violating the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)  It's good to ask the `myclass` itself to give the required description.quoting from this [blog](http://randomthoughtsonjavaprogramming.blogspot.in/2013/10/trainwreck-vs-method-chaining.html).

If in code it looks like this

```
public class A
{
    public void someMethod(B b)
    {
        b.getC().getD().getE().doThing();
    }
}
```

its good to change that to

```
public class A
{
    public void someMethod(B b)
    {
        b.doThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I wanted to follow this advice, I would want to have my `public class B { public ReturnType doThing() {} }` make a call through it's relevant objects (in this case, `public class C {}`) and either pass my return back up, or have any steps perform whatever changes to my returns (if needed; for example if B needs to store a copy of the fetched information to use later, it would do so before passing control back to the original `someMethod()` call)

Comment: yes..The idea here is Object of class c belongs to object b only. If the class A needs it should only ask the object b to give the required value